# Can I get the CefSharp WPF ChromiumWebBrowser to accept IME input?

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I've spent two months creating an immaculate WPF browser app using the [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) embedded Chromium web browser.  Now it was revealed that this browser must work with IME input methods, which it does not.  Essentially, the WPF browser is rendered off-screen, with screen images and input events marshaled back-and-forth.

When the IME is invoked, text entry occurs in a popup tool-window outside of the app, typically in the upper left corner of the desktop.  Once input is accepted, the input is not being marshaled back to the browser.

Is it possible to make the IME appear, as normal, next to the input-field?

I would appreciate some pointers on where to start reading or coding.  If this takes a month to implement, I'm sure it will happen.

update -
It looks like the keys OemAuto and ImeProcessed are being previewed by the WPF browser control (but not passed to the off-screen browser).  Passing those keys to the off-screen browser prevents the IME window from appearing.  I'm not sure if this is progress or not.  :)

update -
I think I'm going to roll my own window message loop to forward IME and input events to the browser. Maybe I can get the browser to handle IME events on its own?

update -
Off-screen IME support does not seems to be implemented on Windows (only Mac)
[CEF3: Windows: Enable IME when Off Screen Rendering is enabled](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=1019). I'm continuing to explore my options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw together a quick hack posted as part of the discussion in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/583 ... but as the proper place to resolve this really is in the CEF codebase I'm hesitating to add the hack the the CefSharp codebase (I'm afraid of side effects for those not needing IME support).

Anyway I hope the CefSharp issue #583 is helpful in bringing you towards a solution - either via the short term hack - or preferably leading to resolution of the CEF issue you already dug up yourself!

Comment: I examined this possible solution but it didn't work like the real thing. I've come to believe that an off-screen IME isn't possible with Windows, so I redesigned the app with WinForm browsers for input and WPF browsers for viewing. The WPF browser is ideal for capturing screenshots and overlaying other content.